# Создание запроса Yandex (ios)

Tags: ios

такой формы требует Google

Request Payload

------WebKitFormBoundaryverRjLKrBwDvUjnS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image_url"

------WebKitFormBoundaryverRjLKrBwDvUjnS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="encoded_image"; filename="ufo.png"
Content-Type: image/png

------WebKitFormBoundaryverRjLKrBwDvUjnS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image_content"

------WebKitFormBoundaryverRjLKrBwDvUjnS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"

------WebKitFormBoundaryverRjLKrBwDvUjnS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="hl"

en
------WebKitFormBoundaryverRjLKrBwDvUjnS--
Код к это му запросу(рабочий)
    request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:30];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

```
NSString *boundary=@"myBoundary";
NSString *FileParamConstant=@"encoded_image";
requestURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"https://www.google.com/searchbyimage/upload"];

//set Content-Type in HTTP header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

//post body
body = [NSMutableData data];

NSDictionary *_params=@{
                        @"image_url":@"",//Content-Disposition
                        @"image_content":@"",
                        @"filename":@"",
                        @"hl":@"en"
                        };
//add params (all params are strings)
for (NSString *param in _params) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [_params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

// add image data
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myTestImage, 0.1);
if (imageData) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[request setHTTPBody:body];
[request setURL:requestURL];
[myWebView loadRequest:request];
```

Такой формы требует Yandex

------WebKitFormBoundaryHYCu5E0BV5ZcR6QT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upfile"; filename="icon.png"
Content-Type: image/png

------WebKitFormBoundaryHYCu5E0BV5ZcR6QT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="format"

json
------WebKitFormBoundaryHYCu5E0BV5ZcR6QT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="request"

[{"block":"b-page_type_search-by-image__link"}]
------WebKitFormBoundaryHYCu5E0BV5ZcR6QT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rpt"

imageview
------WebKitFormBoundaryHYCu5E0BV5ZcR6QT--

Нужно написать запрос Yandex(у меня что то не получается)

Comment: а что вы уже написали?

Comment: Написал запрос к Google-Выше